# How to write a select sum(col), count(other_col) form pandas_df

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner to pandas coming from pyspark and would like to write the following sql query in pandas:

```
select sum(col) as sum_col, count(other_col) as count_other_col from pandas_df
```

I would like this to return a new dataframe.

Thanks.

I've found code that returns the count or total but never in a new dataframe

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @U10-Forward

The expected output should be a new Dataframe that has two columns named sum_col, count_other_col and one row that have values from their respective operations.

Comment: "from their respective operations" what are they?

Comment: so one operation would be `sum` and the other is `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.agg({'col': 'sum', 'other_col': 'count'}).rename({'col': 'sum_col', 'other_col': 'count_other_col'}).to_frame().T
```

Comment: Won't this be deprecated moving forward? I might consider this solution.

Comment: @LawrenceVo The devs have put a lot of effort into standardizing how `.agg` works for DataFrame, GroupBy, and Rolling, .etc. To the best of my knowledge, this approach is what they consider idiomatic. If you have evidence of deprecation, please share.

Comment: @brentertainer wasn't aware to be perfectly honest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using:

```
print(df.assign(col=df['col'].sum(), other_col=df['other_col'].size).iloc[[0]])
```

Comment: doing so only returns the same dataframe back?

Comment: actually returns only the first row of the same dataframe

Comment: @LawrenceVo No it's the sum and the size

Comment: @LawrenceVo can you not just do `agg = pandas_df.agg({'col': 'sum', 'other_col': 'count'})` and then just get your values from its index? So `count_other_col` will be `agg.loc['b']` ?

Comment: @U10-Forward ??

Comment: @JonClements `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'`

Comment: What version of pandas?

Comment: @JonClements 0.19.2

Comment: Ahhh https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html - *new in 0.20.0* - you know we're up to 0.25.0 now... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[pandas_df.col.sum(),pandas_df.other_col.count()]], columns=['sum','count'])
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but was hoping for something that translated better. Will probably end up using this if I can't find anything better.